# метод Split с сохранением знаков препинания

Tags: java

есть такая задача: 
Дан текст, состоящий из предложений. Необходимо пронумеровать предложения в тексте, приписав номер предложения в конце предложения (после знака окончания предложения) в квадратных скобках. Пример: "Мама мыла раму. Вовочка валял дурака..." –> "Мама мыла раму.[1] Вовочка валял дурака.[2].."

```
String str=null;
    try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1.txt"));
        while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
            for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
                for(int i=0; i<sr.length(); i++){
                  String[] word=sr.split("[.?!]");
                  System.out.print(word[i]+"["+(i+1)+"]");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print("Error");
    }
```

В данном случае вывод такой: мама мыла раму[1] вовочка валял дурака[2]Error. 
Что нужно поменять или добавить, чтобы вывод происходил со знаками препинания?
Ещё в самом конце выскакивает "Error". я как то не правильно использую try catch или ошибка в коде?
И, если текст начинается с новой строки, он его не видит, как это исправить?

Comment: `s/"["/".["/` .

Comment: вставила эту конструкцию вот так: split("[s/"["/".["/]"). вывод такой: Error

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вам не кажется, что цикл, вложенный в цикл, вложенный в цикл - это перебор?
Во-вторых, зачем вы используете BufferedReader + FileReader для чтения файлов, если есть более простые способы это сделать?
В-третьих, вы не думали о том, что сплит в данном случае не совсем удобен и рационален?

Для начала давайте отделим чтение файла от логики и выполним это самое чтение чем-то поудобнее, чем BufferedReader + FileReader.
После этого, когда мы имеем не файл, а переменную типа String с нужным нам текстом, создадим метод, который будет принимать исходный текст, хранящийся в переменной String и вернет текст с уже подсчитанными предложениями. Чтобы не создавать дополнительных объектов используем StringBuilder. Переменная String  инкапсулирует в себе массив char, это значит что пройти циклом по этому массиву, доставая каждый char по его индексу, не составит труда. Осталось только сравнить текущий чар с точкой и добавить информавцию о номере предложения. Думаю, что эта реализация максимально простая и понятная

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    private final static String FILE_NAME = "1.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILE_NAME))) {
            String text = stream.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            String result = check(text);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    private static String check(String line) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(line.charAt(i));
            if (line.charAt(i) == '.' && line.charAt(i - 1) != '.') sb.append("[").append(++count).append("]");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! очень помогли

Comment: @user387687 не за что. удачи в изучении